# Splunk: How to enable Splunk SSO

Tags: splunk

I have splunk and try to enable splunk SSO instead of nornal authentiation. I have configuraitons as follows:

In /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/server.conf

```
[general]
trustedIP = 192.168.1.208
serverName = Splunk_Core_02
pass4SymmKey = $7$RRvdYDdIlj4P2geQdtHluTRb7OfvZhTFTZGJ7z5JiZAkJ6Q1at6j0Q==
sessionTimeout = 30s

[sslConfig]
sslPassword = $7$m6pB5a0PWFg64VlNZGgunhGElO3qLiAc6NrhfLO+tpX2jR7WC7qm1Q==

[lmpool:auto_generated_pool_download-trial]
description = auto_generated_pool_download-trial
quota = MAX
slaves = *
stack_id = download-trial

[lmpool:auto_generated_pool_forwarder]
description = auto_generated_pool_forwarder
quota = MAX
slaves = *
stack_id = forwarder

[lmpool:auto_generated_pool_free]
description = auto_generated_pool_free
quota = MAX
slaves = *
stack_id = free

[license]
active_group = Enterprise

[diskUsage]
minFreeSpace = 1024

[lmpool:test_splunk]
quota = MAX
slaves = *
stack_id = enterprise
```

In /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/web.conf

```
[settings]
#SSO
SSOMode = permissive
trustedIP = 192.168.1.208,192.168.2.15,127.0.0.1
remoteUser = REMOTE-USER
#tools.proxy.on = False

root_endpoint = /splunk

#SSL
enableSplunkWebSSL = 0

httpport = 8000

mgmtHostPort = 127.0.0.1:8089

appServerPorts = 8065

splunkdConnectionTimeout = 30

enableSplunkWebClientNetloc = False

# SSL certificate files.
privKeyPath = $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/auth/splunkweb/privkey.pem
serverCert = $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/auth/splunkweb/cert.pem

...
```

I see http://192.168.1.208:8000/debug/sso page, I see SSO is not enabled. What's wrong with my configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several documentations says in `server.conf`, the trustedIP is `127.0.0.1`. But none of them mention that only `127.0.0.1` is eligible to enable/activate `SSO`. So do not configure other IP address, instead of `127.0.0.1`.

And in `server.conf(/opt/splunk/etc/system/local/)`, you could `only` configure `one` trustedIP, and it is `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/Security/ConfigureSplunkSSO

Have you restarted splunk after making these changes?

In /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/web.conf, 
`remoteUser = REMOTE-USER` is more likley to be `REMOTE_USER`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SAML.. I am using SAML for SSO purpose.. You need to contact IT guy and he will provide you IDP file upload it and share with your Splunk Connection file. You can download it from same window. Go to Users -> Authentication Method > SAML. Once everything is placed Then you have to create groups on AD and same thing you need to do on Splunk under SAML configuration.. Let me know if you need more details..

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/Security/HowSAMLSSOworks